# the suggested way to add properties to thirdparty classes in python

Tags: python, inheritance

In python, say that I have a number of classes A, B, C, ... all derived from class "Base".
I need to add a new property(and its related methods) to all those derived classes without modifying Base. Then set the property in **init** function.

I am considering add another base class like

```
class NewBase:
    __init__(self, ...):
        self.new_property = ...

class A1(A, NewBase):

class B1(B, NewBase):

class C1(C, NewBase):
```

but multiple-inheritance introduce other problems.
Is there a suggested way?

Comment: What would like to expect from the classes after fusing the logic of the new class with the classes inheriting from `BaseClass`? Does exposing new class methods and encapsulating the inheriting classes (A, B, C) is reasonable? or you prefer to keep both methods of the inheriting classes and of the new class as a hybrid class? Please elaborate how the new class logic interacts with the inheriting classes

Comment: When you say property, do you actually mean attribute? Because property is something very specific that you actually do add to a class, not an instance.

Comment: "but multiple-inheritance introduce other problems". What problems? Did you actually encouter some, or is this just hearsay?

Comment: Please post an actual MCVE with all the classes involved, and show the desired output. I don't think your grasp of terminology is precise enough to use just prose at the moment. But that's just part of learning and improving.

Comment: @AvivYaniv What I want is equally adding a property to the Base class, which must be set in __init__, and use it in all the derived ones. but I can not modify the existed implements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: In the question above, nor `BaseClass` nor the inheriting `A`, `B` classes can be modified.

***Objective***

We want to add a new property to `BaseClass` in its constructor, which is a `NewClass` instance.

***Solution***

Let's define our `BaseClass` ant its inheriting `A`, `B` classes:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(f'In BaseClass init, got parameters {self.x} {self.y}')

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y)

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y)
```

As well as the `NewClass` that we want to add as property:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_class_property = 'sabich'
        print('In NewClass init')
    def func1(self):
        print('In func1')
    def func2(self):
        print('In func2')
```

Now we can access `BaseClass` constructor with `BaseClass.__init__` and use decorator to wrap additional logic around it:

```
# This decorator wraps adding the new parameter in the constructor
def init_decorator(fun):
    # This would be the returned constructor
    def ret_fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Adding parameter to `NewClass`
        self.parameter = NewClass()
        # Calling the real constructor
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return ret_fun

BaseClass.__init__ = init_decorator(BaseClass.__init__)
```

And it works, by creating an object of type `A`, we can see that it has the parameter property of `NewClass`:

```
# In NewClass init
# In BaseClass init, got parameters 1 2
a = A(1, 2)

# sabich
print(a.parameter.new_class_property)
```

Whole code:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(f'In BaseClass init, got parameters {self.x} {self.y}')

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y)

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y)

class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_class_property = 'sabich'
        print('In NewClass init')
    def func1(self):
        print('In func1')
    def func2(self):
        print('In func2')

def init_decorator(fun):
    def ret_fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parameter = NewClass()
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return ret_fun

BaseClass.__init__ = init_decorator(BaseClass.__init__)

# In NewClass init
# In BaseClass init, got parameters 1 2
a = A(1, 2)

# sabich
print(a.parameter.new_class_property)
```

Comment: using decorator is a creative idea. Does it work with super() calling, but not exactly call the BaseClass method. One more, how about the added property need to be set with a new parameter of init func.

Comment: Thank you @PasserbyD. I don't understand what you mean by the sentence "Does it work with super() calling, but not exactly call the BaseClass method.". Regarding passing parameters to the new property, if you can do it with dependency injection it's much preferable, as passing them directly requires to do this trick for all the inheriting classes A, B, etc...